# Swipe Gesture Recognizer not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, gestures, leap-motion

I am new to c#. I need to make my leap motion to swipe in different direction and each direction (Up, Down, Right and Left) should select some option(picture to navigate to next slide) on my hyperlinked power point presentation.

I am writing a simple c# code to just detect these gestures but it doesn't seem to print anything or do anthing accept being connected.

Please suggest what is going wrong in my code which does not have errors. Or suggest me an alternative way to implement this

```
using System;
using Leap;
using MotionGestures;
using MotionGestures.Enums;

namespace motrial
{

    class LeapListener : Listener
    {

        public override void OnInit(Controller cntrlr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Initialized");
        }

        public override void OnConnect(Controller cntrlr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        }

        public override void OnDisconnect(Controller cntrlr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Disconnected");
        }

        public override void OnExit(Controller cntrlr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exited");
        }

        public void motionDidSwipe(MotionSwipeGestureRecognizer recognizer)
        {
            if (recognizer.state == MotionGestureRecognizerState.MotionGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Swipe did Begin");
            }
            else if (recognizer.state == MotionGestureRecognizerState.MotionGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
            {
                //System.Console.WriteLine("Swipe did Change");
            }
            else if (recognizer.state == MotionGestureRecognizerState.MotionGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
            {
                //Handle swipe end
                if (recognizer.direction == MotionSwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.MotionSwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Swipe Left");
                }
                else if (recognizer.direction == MotionSwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.MotionSwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Swipe Right");
                }
                else if (recognizer.direction == MotionSwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.MotionSwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Swipe Up");
                }
                else if (recognizer.direction == MotionSwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.MotionSwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Swipe Down");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What LM software version are you using? Note that the Orion software does not have Swipe gesture support.

Comment: I am using the V2 desktop version. This just prints connected and initialized.No gesture detected. Why is that so?

Comment: It isn't clear from the code shown why anything happens at all. Is that the whole program? Is the MotionGestures package automatically setting up the Controller for you and adding your listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude, stop using those gestures, LM remove them from Orion because they are very unreliable.
You will need to build your own if you really wants this to work as expected.